# Google Apps Script - 2d Variable - How to declare?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need a declaration of the variable Lon_Final / Lon Temp / Lat_Final / Lat_temp. The value-range is i = 4 To 200 and p = 0 To 300. I am used to the way in VBA. `Dim Lon_Temp(3000, 3000) As Double`I am looking for the equivalent in Google Apps Script.

```
  for (var i = 4; i <= last_row; i++){
  for(var p = 0; p <= Count_Geodata[i]; p=p+2){
            Lon_Final[i, p] = Lon_Temp[i, Count_Geodata[i] - p - 1];
            Lat_Final[i, p] = Lat_Temp[i, Count_Geodata[i] - p - 1];}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found and what works for me....

```
var Lon_Final = new Array(3000);
    for (var i = 0; i < Lon_Final.length; i++) {
      Lon_Final[i] = new Array(3000);
    }
```

and it can be used like in the following sample:

```
Lon_Final[i][p] = Lon_Temp[i][p];
```